# React Native Component Won't Appear

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im trying to create reusable flatlist component called `TrendingList`, the first one works, but the item below it doesn't appear. Im so confused cause i dont know how to solve this.

```
    <View>
     <TrendingList data={MovieResult} nav={navigation} />
    </View>
    <View>
     <TrendingList data={TV} />
    </View>
```

Please Help:D

Comment: add more code so that we can understand the problem,,, add code fofr TrendingList

Comment: sorry for not attaching the flatlist component, cz when i paste it here it become messy cz the lint. Maybe you can tell me how to do it:D

Comment: send a screenshot or refarance hoe you want the ui to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
       <TrendingList data={MovieResult} nav={navigation} />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
       <TrendingList data={TV} />
    </View>
<View>
```